# What different meanings does 'virtue' have in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

"But by the virtue of being born a Brahmin - a virtue, indeed! - he must have had exposure to more affluent situations and people".

What does the 2 'virtue' mean in the above sentence?

Comment: 'By virtue of [being born a]' is a bleached expression nowadays meaning little more than 'Due to the fact that [he was born a]'. It would however sound wrong if used with a pejorative 'By virtue of being found guilty of shoplifting ...'. / The second instance is the usual 'nobility' sense, with connotations of privilege.  But these are easily found in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for help Edwin! One thing I would like to say here is that your explanation wasn't lucid enough for me to understand completely (which obviously is because of my lack of understanding of English, Words like pejorative and bleached expressions were out of my understanding), but I took my time to absorb all you wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context. You need to parse whether the author is saying that a Brahmin is inherently moral or whether the author is saying being born a Brahmin is a lucky privilege. Since a "Brahmin" is the highest ranking of the four social classes in Hinduism, it could be the former. But it's more likely the latter. I would look at the Merriam-Webster's definition of virtue that is defined as "a beneficial quality." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtue

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your beautiful explanation. Considering your explanation and my thoughts, I would say that your latter meaning should be right considering that "he had exposure to more affluent situations and people".  Really thanks though.